# Testing the value of an item in a sequence

Tags: expl3

I'm trying to test the value of an item in a sequence. The approach below doesn't seem to work. Could someone suggest a fix or alternative?

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\tl_new:N \l_test_tl
\seq_new:N \l_test_seq

\tl_set:Nn \l_test_tl { a }
\seq_set_from_clist:Nn \l_test_seq { a,b }

\begin{document}

\str_if_eq:VnTF { \l_test_tl } { a } { 1 } { 0 } \hspace{1em} % returns 1, as expected

\seq_item:Nn { \l_test_seq } { 1 } \hspace{1em} % returns a, as expected

\str_if_eq:VnTF { \seq_item:Nn { \l_test_seq } { 1 } } { a } { 1 } { 0 } \hspace{1em} % returns 0

\str_if_eq:nnTF { \seq_item:Nn { \l_test_seq } { 1 } } { a } { 1 } { 0 } % returns 0

\end{document}
```

Comment: Try `\str_if_eq:eeTF`

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik That's got it, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\str_if_eq:nnTF` (emphasis on `:nn`) will treat the arguments literally (without expansion), so it compares the *characters* `\seq_item:Nn { \l_test_seq } { 1 }` with `a` which is obviously wrong.

`\str_if_eq:VnTF` expands the `V`alue of the first argument, but the argument for `V` *must be* a single variable, and not arbitrary commands.  For example, you could use `\str_if_eq:VnTF \l_tmpa_str ...`, but not `\str_if_eq:VnTF { \str_use:N \l_tmpa_str } ...`.

What you want here is the *full expansion* of `\seq_item:Nn`, so you have to use the `e` variant: `\str_if_eq:eeTF` (`e` is an *exhaustive* expansion: it expands everything that can be expanded).