# Items in a sequence can't be called with \left and \right

Tags: expl3

Could someone please explain to me what's going on here?

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\begin{document}

\[
\seq_new:N \l_args_seq
\seq_set_from_clist:Nn \l_args_seq { (,) }
\seq_use:Nn \l_args_seq {} \\ % both items show up
\left{\seq_item:Nn \l_args_seq { 1 }}
hi
\right{\seq_item:Nn \l_args_seq { 2 }} % "Missing delimeter" message
\]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\left` and `\right` are TeX primitives which take exactly a single token as argument, so when you write `\left{<things>}`, TeX sees `\left {` and complains that `{` is not a valid delimiter (and things go completely wrong from here on).  Same as in your [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/596293/134574) about `\str_if_eq:eeTF`, you need to first force the expansion of `\seq_item:Nn` and then pass the resulting token to `\left` and `\right`.

Here's are two commands `\Left` and `\Right` that take any input as argument, expands it, then passes the resulting token to `\left` and `\right`, respectively.  If the expanded input results in more than one token, an error is raised and only the first token is used.

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand \Left { m }
  { \mjc_math_delim:Ne \left {#1} }
\NewDocumentCommand \Right { m }
  { \mjc_math_delim:Ne \right {#1} }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \mjc_math_delim:Nn #1 #2
  {
    \tl_if_single_token:nTF {#2}
      { #1 #2 }
      {
        \msg_error:nnn { mjc } { multi-token-delim } {#2}
        \exp_last_unbraced:Ne #1 { \tl_head:n {#2} }
      }
  }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \mjc_math_delim:Nn { Ne }
\msg_new:nnn { mjc } { multi-token-delim }
  {
    Argument~must~expand~to~a~single~token.\\
    You~passed~'#1'~as~argument.
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\[
\seq_new:N \l_args_seq
\seq_set_from_clist:Nn \l_args_seq { (,) }
\seq_use:Nn \l_args_seq {} \\ % both items show up
\Left{\seq_item:Nn \l_args_seq { 1 }}
\frac{1}{2}
\Right{\seq_item:Nn \l_args_seq { 2 }} % "Missing delimeter" message
\]

\end{document}
```